# Redshift SUM function issue

Tags: sql, sum, amazon-redshift

I am facing an issue with the SUM function of the redshift.

I just used

```
SUM(col1) as T1 from "table_name" where ...
```

to fetch the data. Which have numeric type values in data type varchar of the column.

But it is not giving me correct total amount in T1.

An eg. col1 have two different row with the amount of "34.50". So it should return 69. But it is returning 68.

column "col1" data type is varchar.

Comment: Well, what do you expect if you use the wrong types?  Fix the data and you'll fix your problem.

Comment: **Never**, ever store numbers in `varchar` columns. As Gordon said: fix your data model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't use the correct datatype, try casting it before like this:

```
SUM(col1::numeric) as T1 from "table_name" where ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In redshift the easiest way to convert datatypes is like this

```
SUM(col1::numeric) as T1 from "table_name" where ...
```